# Bad request from redirect url setting up a new authentication connection setting for Instagram on Azure Bot Service

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to set up a new connection setting for Instagram on Azure as described on this tutorial (https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/AI-Show/Conversational-AI-and-Authentication) at time 2:30 to OAuth with a Card in Skype

The issue seems to be with the redirect url when coming back to https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect

I am currently trying to use OAuthCard in my Skype Bot using

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-oauth/app.js

I am using this OAuthCard in Skype - I click it and it redirects, asks for approval to my account/sign in - I give it and it then redirects and give a blank white screen with "Bad request"

I am expecting it to return to the Skype chat and continue the dialog

It redirects to:https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect?code=xyz&state=abc

N.B. If I go to my Instagram account I can see that I have given my app access, so it is not an issue there.

Comment: Is there any information on the error in the query string of the url on the page displaying `bad request`? I have been trying to reproduce this error but I cannot, it just works or displays a JSON error for me.

Comment: When I redirect I get https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect?code=xyz&state=abc there is no bad request information

Comment: I am getting a response from instagram in that they send the url back with "code" and "state" - the only line of code I have changed is 
    var builder = require('../../core/');
to
    var builder = require('botbuilder'); - perhaps this is the issue? Is ../../core/ a module I need to install and I don't need botbuilder?

Comment: Also if it helps - when trying to set up a new oauth connection in azure bot service settings, with Twitter and pressing test connection, I get a bad request before reaching twitter - which is odd as I only have to put in the consumer Key and Secret

Comment: This is really odd because I am able to get this working in Skype and other channels with no issues.  I have even tried to put in wrong values for everything and am still unable to reproduce the `bad request`.  Have you tried revoking access in your IG account and retrying?  If you could also post an issue in our [github repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new)  so we can better track this we would appreciate it.

Comment: Yep I have revoked access - so it takes me back to the authorization page (which is a sandbox mode - could that be an issue?) - then it redirects to the aforementioned address with bad request and the code and state in the query string

Comment: I have also set the verified redirect url in the instagram sandbox client to "https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect"

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Hello, has anyone been able to solve this issue? Would love some insights.